# How to modify logo and css style for emails templates in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, css, email-templates

I need to set a new logo and make some css adjustments for emails like "password-reset" in magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting up your custom logo:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Design -> Email -> Logo Image**

There you can upload your custom logo image and then, also in

**Stores -> Configuration -> Design -> Email**

You can set up your logo width and height.

You can also modify your password-reset email trhough Magento Admin in

**Marketing -> Email Templates**

And Add your custom Email template for Password Reset as it is explained **[here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#customize-email-admin)**.

If you want to avoid using your common header and calling your logo "as is" and then inline-styling it, this is the var you need to put as "src" attribute.

**{{var logo_url}}**

EDIT:

If what you want to do is to edit your email template using your theme [you can look here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#customize-email-theme) it shows you how to use the template fallback to achieve it. Should be something like copying and editing

**app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/email/password_reset.html**

in your

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/email/password_reset.html**

(I didn't try this yet, but according to the documentation it should work)

Comment: I don't want to do it in the backend. I need to solve this based on code. that's why I asked what files I have to modify

Comment: I just updated the info with what I think it's the way to do it.

Comment: But where are the LESS files?!?!? and which one exactly??!?!?! you are not answering my question

Comment: Anyway, you can place your LESS files in

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/email-inline.less**

and base it on [this template] (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/email-inline.less) of magento core files.

Answer (score 0):

in Magento 2, 
for edit email style, need add style file to your theme.

in **web/css/email-inline.css**

and can add style, like this (logo centered)

```
.wrapper .header {
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

after,
need run commands from console

*php bin/magento setup:upgrade*

*php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f*

*php bin/magento setup:upgrade*

And send test email.