# How can i send Company logo in custom email templates

Tags: magento2, email-templates, logo

how can i send company logo in custom email templates ?
 I know that it is placed on header.html 
in `vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email`

Comment: Refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106922/how-to-modify-logo-and-css-style-for-emails-templates/106934

Comment: i tried that but not working for me

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** We can use block technique. And put it where you want. For example, insert this block in your template:

```
{{block class='Company\\Module\\Block\\Email\\Logo' 
area='frontend' template='Company_Module::email/logo.phtml'}}
```

Your custom block:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block\Email;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Logo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $logo;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $logo,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get logo image URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogoSrc()
    {
        return $this->logo->getLogoSrc();
    }

}
```

Template: `view/templates/email/logo.phtml`

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Company\Module\Block\Email\Logo */
/** @var $this  \Company\Module\Block\Email\Logo*/
?>

<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc()?>" alt="<?php echo __('Logo Image'); ?>"/>
```

See more here: `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html`

Comment: In header.html ?

Comment: Anywhere you want.

Comment: It's not working :(   i put this header.html which included in my custom email template ?

Comment: Try `<img src="{{view url='Magento_Email/logo_email.png'}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Logo'}}" />`.

Comment: Should i move header.html file and less files (email-inline.less and email.less) in my theme folder under module-email folder ?

Comment: This code I show above. It worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately its not working @Khoa :(